# armadillo how to get rid of error message

Tags: armadillo

Running the following code still produces an error message that goes to stdout (not stderr) although the exception was successfully caught:

```
Mat<double> matrix_quantiles(const vector<double> & quantiles,
                         const Mat<double> & m) {
  Mat<double> sorted_matrix;
  try {
    sorted_matrix = arma::sort(arma::cor(m));
  } catch(std::logic_error & e) {
  /*
   Sometimes a col is constant, causing the correlation to be
   infinite. If that happens, add normal random jitter to the
   values and retry.
  */
  const Mat<double> jitter = Mat<double>(
    m.n_rows, m.n_cols, arma::fill::randn);
  return matrix_quantiles(quantiles, 1.e-3 * jitter + m);
} 
etc.
```

The error message is:

```
error: sort(): given object has non-finite elements
```

The code runs fine, and the jittering strategy is good enough for what I do, but I have to filter out the error message if I write the output to stdout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable printing of error messagaes, define a macro named `ARMA_DONT_PRINT_ERRORS` before including the Armadillo header.  For example:

```
#define ARMA_DONT_PRINT_ERRORS
#include <armadillo>
```

Comment: More info on configuring Armadillo is in the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp)